# Google Maps: Simple app not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-maps

We have a simple Google Maps traffic application up at: http://www.avonandsomerset.police.uk/newsroom/traffic/

For some reason it's recently stopped working in IE correctly. At this point in time it was using V2 of the API, so I've just upgraded it to use V3 - but it still won't work in IE.

It **works fine in Chrome** & **Firefox**. But in all versions of IE I've tired (6,7,8) the Google Map doesn't load fully.

**The problem**
The Google Map DIV will generally load all the controls (Zoom, Powered by Google, map types) but the actual map tiles do not appear in IE. I can just see the grey background of the DIV>

**What I've tried**
I've commented down the JavaScript code to just the following on the page, but it still has the same problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" > 

    var map;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        initialize(); // Set-up Google map        
    });

    function initialize() {
        var options = {
            zoom: 9,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.335759, -2.870178),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), options);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Ooooh! I had this problem once! Trying to remember how I fixed it...

Comment: Do the examples at Google work from your IE? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/examples/index.html

Comment: Yes, the Google Map examples do work. Which is strange, because the code above I initially took from an example. It seems something else on the page is interfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally tracked the problem down.

Turns out someone else had included the **[sleight.js](http://allinthehead.com/retro/69/sleight-of-hand)** script () in our Master Page.

This JavaScript is designed to get PNG transparency working in IE5.5+, however a knock on affect is that it stops Google Maps working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going completely from memory here, but try inserting `var` just before you greate the Map object and removing the `var map` at the top. So:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map...
```

I can confidently state that the problem is with IE and global/local variables, ie, your map variable.

Comment: I've tried as you've suggested, commenting out the global 'var map' and scoping the 'var map' to inside the initialize() function - but the map still isn't loading correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it might be a cross-browser difference in function hoisting. Try declaring your initialize function before your document ready block.